# Permission denied when trying to mount nfs on Ubuntu 22.01

Tags: permissions, mount, 22.04, nfs, compatibility

My servers are all on Ubuntu 20.04 except one that I have migrated to 22.04 as a test. I encountered a problem mounting a shared scratch disk that is part of my backend network.

The answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405231/unable-to-mount-nfs-on-ubuntu-22-04) did not work, all related to nfs version issues.

In addition to those suggesetions, I checked and double checked that the shared drive was exported and the fstab was correctly setup.

Of course the nfs versions are different, but the all services are started, enabled, and support the same subset of nfs protocols.

ANy Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the answer is in a difference between what syntax 20.04 and 22.04 support for the export statment in /etc/exports

In my existing setup I have

```
/mnt/toexport 123.45.67.*(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

Maybe this is bad form for specifying the entire IP range? To get the permissions set correctly, I needed the following in 22.04

```
/mnt/toexport 123.45.67.0/24(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

note that running

```
sudo exportfs -avr
```

did not complain with the old (apparently broken) syntax.